# Javascript, count number of key/values inside stringified JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

Hello I have an object that I'm convertion into JSON like that :

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObject);
```

the `console.log(myJSON);` gives :

```
[{"RowID":"6","Name":"joe","Alias":"ss","Email":"ss@gmail.com","Phone":"123456"}]
```

How can I count the number of keys inside that json? I want to count 5 items as a result :

RowID, Name, Alias, Email, Phone

I tried to count the elements within the object before the JSON stringify  with :
`console.log(Object.keys(myObject).length);` but it gives me 1 not 5

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `myObject` is an array. You need to access *the first item of the array* to get your 5-keyed object.

```
Object.keys(myObject[0]).length
```